# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JobListener name cannot be empty

Tags: java

i am trying to listen the job which is scheduled but i am getting the below error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JobListener name cannot be empty.

Comment: The output says you are missing the `name` param, or its a empty string, post your code so that others can check it.

Comment: Given what you have asked, the only possible answer is supply a name to the job listener. To get a more helpful answer, you will need to provide some more details. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The `IllegalArgumentException` is generally used to indicate (surprise surprise), that an argument passed to the method is illegal. The validity checks depend on whatever is decided by your implementation. If you need more help, you should specify what library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You should have implemented `JobListener`
and overridden method below

```
@Override
public String getName() {
    return "my-job-listener"; // do not return null here
}
```

Make sure its not returning null.